# Send post request to Algorithmia API from Power BI Desktop

Tags: rest, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, algorithmia

I'm trying to get data from an Algorithmia API into Power BI Desktop.

Basically, trying to convert this:

```
curl -X POST -d '"Test"' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Simple simAOH0ixjNUwV/qBMh1BW1fbKH1' https://api.algorithmia.com/v1/algo/tone/DemoAlgo/0.1.0?timeout=300
```

Into Power Query M:

```
let
url= "https://api.algorithmia.com/v1/algo/tone/DemoAlgo/0.1.0",
auth_key = "'Simple simAOH0ixjNUwV/qBMh1BW1fbKH1'",
header = [#"Authorization" = auth_key, #"Content-Type" = "application/json"],
query = "'Test'",
webdata = Web.Contents(url, [Headers=header, Query = query]),
response = Json.Document(webdata)
in
response
```

This is returning `NOT found error: 404`.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a bit of a shot in the dark with this since I'm fairly new at using APIs myself, but from looking at [the API documentation for Algorithmia](https://algorithmia.com/developers/api/#get-an-algorithm), I think you might not be using the right end-point designation. I believe you might need to use: `https://api.algorithmia.com/v1/algorithms/:username/:algoname`. I believe you substituted algo for algorithms. I also think you might need to remove the apostrophes (single quotes like ') from auth_key and query.

Hopefully this helps you get closer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for helping out.

I've made it with this:

```
let 
    url= "https://api.algorithmia.com/v1/algo/tone/DemoAlgo/0.1.0?timeout=300",
    auth_key = "simAOH0ixjNUwV/qBMh1BW1fbKH1",
    header = [#"Authorization" = auth_key, #"Content-Type" = "application/json"],
    post_contents = """Teste""",
    
    webdata = Web.Contents(url, [Content=Text.ToBinary(post_contents), Headers=header]),
    response = Json.Document(webdata)
in
    response
```